# Download a file from Huawei cloud using official SDK

Tags: go, download, huawei-developers, huawei-cloud

I'm trying to download files from Huawei, more precisely from their cloud storage. The issue is, I have been unable to connect to it.

I found an [SDK from Huawei](https://github.com/huaweicloud/huaweicloud-sdk-go-v3), but I'm a little lost on all the protocol I can use to connect to it, and I haven't been able to make one working, each time. And the documentations are not very helpful.

I also found [this](https://github.com/huaweicloud/huaweicloud-sdk-go-obs). There is an example of downloading a file. Here, I can't even connect to Huawei. In the AppGalery, project settings, I downloaded the configuration file and tried the endpoint, but without success.

Here is what I tried with obs (I know/guess it should be agc, but I haven't found a package for it), but not working due to the host.

```
/**
 * This sample demonstrates how to download an object
 * from OBS in different ways using the OBS SDK for Go.
 */
package huawei

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"

    "github.com/huaweicloud/huaweicloud-sdk-go-obs/obs"
)

type DownloadSample struct {
    bucketName string
    objectKey  string
    location   string
    obsClient  *obs.ObsClient
}

func newDownloadSample(ak, sk, endpoint, bucketName, objectKey, location string) *DownloadSample {
    obsClient, err := obs.New(ak, sk, endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return &DownloadSample{obsClient: obsClient, bucketName: bucketName, objectKey: objectKey, location: location}
}

func (sample DownloadSample) GetObject() {
    input := &obs.GetObjectInput{}
    input.Bucket = sample.bucketName
    input.Key = sample.objectKey

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", input)
    output, err := sample.obsClient.GetObject(input)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        errMsg := output.Body.Close()
        if errMsg != nil {
            panic(errMsg)
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("Object content:")
    body, err := io.ReadAll(output.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    fmt.Println()
}

func RunDownloadSample() {
    const (
        endpoint   = "theEndPointInConfigJSONFile"
        ak         = "prettySureOfThis"
        sk         = "prettySureOfThis"
        bucketName = "prettySureOfThis"
        objectKey  = "test.txt" // a txt in the bucket to try to download it
        location   = ""
    )
    sample := newDownloadSample(ak, sk, endpoint, bucketName, objectKey, location)

    fmt.Println("Download object to string")
    sample.GetObject()
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your question misses crictical details: "I can't even connect to Huawei" is not a problem statement because basically the only response could be "then there is some problem" which is not very useful. To be actionable, the question has to provide exact error messages of the code being executed (and failing).

Comment: One has to obtain an auth token, to begin with: https://github.com/huaweicloud/huaweicloud-sdk-go-obs/blob/master/obs/auth.go#L117

Answer (score 0):

May you try the official OBS SDK?

**OBS SDK for GO**
https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/sdk-go-devg-obs/obs_33_0001.html

**Different types of download:**
https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/sdk-go-devg-obs/obs_23_0501.html

**Normal download + Code:**
https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/sdk-go-devg-obs/obs_23_0502.html

```
// Import a dependency.
import (
       "fmt"
       "obs"
)

var ak = "*** Provide your Access Key ***"
var sk = "*** Provide your Secret Key ***"
// Replace the following region with the one in use. Here uses the CN-Hong Kong region as an example.
var endPoint = "https://obs.ap-southeast-1.myhuaweicloud.com"

// Create an ObsClient struct.
var obsClient, _ = obs.New(ak, sk, endPoint)

func main() {
       input := &obs.GetObjectInput{}
       input.Bucket = "bucketname"
       input.Key = "objectname"
       output, err := obsClient.GetObject(input)
       if err == nil {
              defer output.Body.Close()
              fmt.Printf("StorageClass:%s, ETag:%s, ContentType:%s, ContentLength:%d, LastModified:%s\n",
                     output.StorageClass, output.ETag, output.ContentType, output.ContentLength, output.LastModified)
              p := make([]byte, 1024)
              var readErr error
              var readCount int
              // Read the object content.
              for {
                     readCount, readErr = output.Body.Read(p)
                     if readCount > 0 {
                           fmt.Printf("%s", p[:readCount])
                     }
                     if readErr != nil {
                           break
                     }
              }
       } else if obsError, ok := err.(obs.ObsError); ok {
              fmt.Printf("Code:%s\n", obsError.Code)
              fmt.Printf("Message:%s\n", obsError.Message)
       }
}
```